# Jquery and media query without page resize

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gw4dx575/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).resize(function(){    
            if ($(".responsive-screen").css("content") === "M" ){
                console.log('mobile');
            }else{
                console.log('desktop');
            }
        });
    })
```

I need a simple method to have different jquery events on different devices/screen sizes (hover on desktop and click on mobile).

I'm using the method described here - http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

It works by checking if a media query is set when the page is resized.

My problem is I need it to work when the page isn't resized like when the page loads on a mobiel device.

This point is made and the response is to check outside the window.resize function.

How do I check outside the window.resize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by two ways:

**Method 1: Define a function that is called upon DOM ready, and called again during resize events**

This method involves defining a function, say `fluid()`, and then also firing it when the window resize event is triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fluid = function() {
        if ($(".responsive-screen").css("content") === "M" ){
            console.log('mobile');
        } else {
            console.log('desktop');
        }
    };

    // Fire on DOM ready
    fluid();

    // Fire upon resize
    $(window).resize(fluid);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gw4dx575/4/

---

**Method 2: Fire `.resize()` on DOM ready**

Alternatively, you can choose to [trigger the resize event again](http://api.jquery.com/resize/#resize) by chaining it to the `$(window)` object. A longer, but more verbose equivalent would be `.trigger('resize')` :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(".responsive-screen").css("content") === "M" ){
                console.log('mobile');
            } else {
                console.log('desktop');
            }        
    }).resize();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gw4dx575/3/